# How to calculate string array with numbers and arithmetic operations

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm trying to create a calculator using only an array that contains arithmetic symbols and numbers, but I can't figure out how to actually calculate the result since my array will only have strings. By the way, I'm using Python 3.11.

Example of an array:

```
# Example 1
arr = ['2', '*', '2']  # 2x2 = 4 <- This should be the result

# Example 2 - More Complex
arr = ['(', '1', '6', '*', '0', ')', '+', '(', '1', '6', '*', '1', ')', '+', '5']  # (16x0) + (16x1) + 5 = 21 <- This should be the result
```

I have tried joining the array using `''.join(arr)`, but it only returns the items in the array since they are all strings and not the result.

I have tried joining the array using `''.join(arr)`, but it only returns the items in the array since they are all strings and not the result.

I have also tried splitting the array by the arithmetic simbols and converting the numbers from strings to integers, but I had some problems with floating numbers, such as 1.10, 2.42, 4.17 and so on.

Comment: You will need to write a tokenizer and parser. You can combine digits together to make a number then do the appropriate arithmetic operation when you see an operator.

Comment: If you want to cheat, you can do `result = eval(''.join(arr))`, but it is both entertaining and educational to write an expression evaluator like this.  Take it one character at a time, building up an accumulator as long as you get digits.  It's tricky to handle precedence and parentheses, but there are web guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using eval:

```
def evaluate_expression(arr):
    expression = ''.join(arr)
    result = eval(expression)
    return result
arr = ['2', '*', '2']
result = evaluate_expression(arr)
print(result)  # Output: 4

arr = ['(', '1', '6', '*', '0', ')', '+', '(', '1', '6', '*', '1', ')', '+', '5']
result = evaluate_expression(arr)
print(result)  # Output: 21
```

if you dont want to use `eval()` function, the labor way would be using stack:

```
def evaluate_expression(arr):
    precedence = {'+': 1, '-': 1, '*': 2, '/': 2, '^': 3}

    output_queue = []
    operator_stack = []
    for token in arr:
        if token.isdigit() or '.' in token:
            output_queue.append(token)
        elif token in precedence:
            while operator_stack and operator_stack[-1] != '(' and precedence[operator_stack[-1]] >= precedence[token]:
                output_queue.append(operator_stack.pop())
            operator_stack.append(token)
        elif token == '(':
            operator_stack.append(token)
        elif token == ')':
            while operator_stack[-1] != '(':
                output_queue.append(operator_stack.pop())
            operator_stack.pop()
    while operator_stack:
        output_queue.append(operator_stack.pop())

    stack = []
    for token in output_queue:
        if token.isdigit() or '.' in token:
            stack.append(float(token))
        elif token in precedence:
            operand2 = stack.pop()
            operand1 = stack.pop()
            if token == '+':
                result = operand1 + operand2
            elif token == '-':
                result = operand1 - operand2
            elif token == '*':
                result = operand1 * operand2
            elif token == '/':
                result = operand1 / operand2
            elif token == '^':
                result = operand1 ** operand2
            stack.append(result)

    return stack.pop()

arr = ['2', '*', '2']
result = evaluate_expression(arr)
print(result)  # Output: 4.0

arr = ['(', '1', '6', '*', '0', ')', '+', '(', '1', '6', '*', '1', ')', '+', '5']
result = evaluate_expression(arr)
print(result)  # Output: 21.0
```